# Error en actualizar o modificar datos desde php o html a base de datos

Tags: php

estoy practicando en un curso de desarrollo web back end y tengo todos los archivos, lo que no hacen las páginas es actualizar con usuario nuevo o existente algunos de sus datos. O también eliminarlos o crear un usuario nuevo. No se donde empezar a mostrar el código, accedi a su sitio porque me resolvio mucha la sintaxis con errores que aparecian al escribirlo: Dejo los dos primeros archivos o mejor subo todo a ver que me falta. La base de datos funciona pero me falta algo.

gracias

**basedatos.php:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        function conectar_bd(){
            $servidor = "localhost";
            $nombrebd = "empresa";
            $usuario = 'root';
            $contraseña = "";
            
            $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña);
            mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $nombrebd);
            return $conexion;
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Prueba.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include("basedatos.php");
        $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
        mysqli_close($conexionbd);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Nuevoempleado.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Nuevo empleado</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="agregarempleado.php" method="post" name="nuevoempleado">
            <input type="text" name="empleado_nombre">
            </br>
            <input type="number" name="empleado_edad">
            </br>
            <input type="submit" name="Agregar empleado">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

agregarempleado.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include('basedatos.php');
        if(!empty($_POST['empleado_nombre'])&& !empty($_POST['empleado_edad'])){
            $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
            $query = "INSERT INTO empleado (nombre,edad) VALUES (' ". 
            $_POST['empleado_nombre']. " ',' ". $_POST['empleado_edad']. " ')";
            $exito = mysqli_query($query, $conexionbd);
            if($exito)
            {
         

   header('Location: listaempleados.php');
        } else{
            header('Location: nuevoempleado.php');
        }
    } else{
        header('Location: nuevoempleado.php');
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Listaempleados.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include("basedatos.php");
        $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexionbd,'SELECT * FROM empleado' );
        mysqli_close($conexionbd);
        ?>
        <h1>Lista empleados</h1>
        <ul>
            <?php
            while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                echo "<li>" . $registro['nombre']. '('. $registro['edad']. 'años)';
                echo '<a href = "modificarempleado.php?empleadoid = ' . $registro['id']. ' "> 
                Modificar</a></li>';
                echo '<a href = "eliminarempleado.php?empleadoid = ' . $registro['id']. ' 
                ">Eliminar</a></li>';
            }
            ?>
            
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Modificarempleado.php

```
         <?php
        
          include('basedatos.php');
          $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
          error_reporting(error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE);
          $id = $_GET['id'];
          $query = "SELECT id,nombre,edad * FROM empleado  WHERE id='$id'";
          $resultado=$conexionbd->query($query);
            mysqli_close($conexionbd);
            if($resultado) {    
            while($registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                echo $row['nombre'];
                echo $row['edad'];
            }
            }
           ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="actualizarempleado.php" method="post" name="nuevoempleado">
            <input type="text" name="empleado_nombre" value="<?php echo $registro['nombre']? 
             >">
            <br/>
            <input type="number" name="empleado_edad" value="<?php echo $registro['edad']?>">
            <br/>
            <input type="hidden" name="empleado_id" value="<?php echo $registro['id']?>">
            <br/>
            <input type ="submit" name="Actualizar empleado">
        </form>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Actualizarempleado.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        include('basedatos.php');
        if(!empty($_POST['empleado_nombre'])&& !empty($_POST['empleado_edad'])&& !
        !empty($_POST['empleado_id'])){
                $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
                $query = "UPDATE  empleado SET nombre = ' ". $_POST['empleado_nombre']. " ', 
         edad = ' ". $_POST['empleado_edad']. " ' WHERE id = ".$_POST['empleado_id'];
            $exito = mysqli_query($conexionbd, $query);
            if($exito)
            {
                header('Location: listaempleados.php');
            } else{
                header('Location: nuevoempleado.php');
            }
        } else{
            header('Location: nuevoempleado.php');
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Eliminarempleado.php

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            include('basedatos.php');
            if(!empty($_GET['empleado_id'])){
                $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
                $query = "DELETE FROM empleado WHERE id = " .$_GET['empleado_id'];
                $exito = mysqli_query($conexionbd,$query);
                mysqli_close($conexionbd);
                if($exito)
                {
                    header('Location: listaempleados.php');
                } else{
                    header('Location: listaempleados.php');
                }
            }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
    
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            include('basedatos.php');
            if(!empty($_GET['empleado_id'])){
                $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
                $query = "DELETE FROM empleado WHERE id = " .$_GET['empleado_id'];
                $exito = mysqli_query($conexionbd,$query);
                mysqli_close($conexionbd);
                if($exito)
                {
                    header('Location: listaempleados.php');
                } else{
                    header('Location: listaempleados.php');
                }
            }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Haré pruebas con tu código. Aunque no te recomiendo utilizar la letra **Ñ** en variables como esta: `$contraseña = "";`

Comment: En `agregarempleado.php` donde usas `mysqli_query()` tienes los argumentos al revés, primero es la conexión y luego la consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me di a la tarea de ayudarte un poco. Para no crear tantos archivos, utilicé un archivo llamado acciones, al cual irán tus forms dependiendo si vas a agregar, eliminar o actualizar.

**BASEDEDATOS.PHP**

```
<?php
$servidor = "localhost";
$nombrebd = "test";
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";

#CREAR CONEXION
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $nombrebd);

#VALIDAR QUE SI ESTAS CONECTADX
if (!$conn) {
    die("Falló la conexion: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**NUEVOEMPLEADO.PHP**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>VER/ACTUALIZAR EMPLEADO</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php 
        #CONEXION A BD
        include_once('basededatos.php');
        
        #RECIBE UNA VARIABLE
        if(isset($_GET['vista'])){
            $vista = $_GET['vista']; 
        }else{
            $vista = 'addEmpleado'; #vista por defecto
        }
        

        #VISTA PARA CARGAR EL FORMULARIO DE AGREGAR EMPLEADO
        if($vista=='addEmpleado'){
            
            #MUESTRA UNA ALERTA
            if(isset($_GET['alerta'])){ echo '<script> Swal.fire("'.$_GET['alerta'].'") </script>'; } 
        
            echo '
                <h1>Nuevo empleado</h1>
                <form action="acciones.php?action=add_empleado" method="post" name="nuevoempleado" style="width: 400px;">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                    </br>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="edad" placeholder="Edad">
                    </br>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Agregar empleado">
                    <a href="listaempleados.php" class="btn btn-danger" >Cancelar</a>
                </form>';
        }

        #VISTA PARA CARGAR EL FORMULARIO DE ACTUALIZAR EMPLEADO
        if($vista=='updateEmpleado'){

            #RECIBE EL ID DEL EMPLEADO
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            #CONSULTA LOS DATOS DEL EMPLEADO CON EL ID
            $query = "SELECT * FROM empleado WHERE ID = $id";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

            #RECORRES LOS RESULTADOS DE LA CONSULTA
            foreach($resultado as $rows){
                $nombre =$rows['nombre'];
                $edad =$rows['edad'];
            }

            echo '
            <h1>Nuevo empleado</h1>
            <form action="acciones.php?action=modificarEmpleado" method="post" style="width: 400px;">
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id" placeholder="Nombre" value="'.$id.'">
                </br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="'.$nombre.'">
                </br>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="edad" placeholder="Edad" value="'.$edad.'">
                </br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Modificar empleado">
                <a href="listaempleados.php" class="btn btn-danger" >Cancelar</a>
            </form>';

        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**LISTAEMPLEADOS.PHP**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Lista empleados</h1>

        <?php
            include_once('basededatos.php');
            
            #MUESTRA UNA ALERTA
            if(isset($_GET['alerta'])){ echo '<script> Swal.fire("'.$_GET['alerta'].'") </script>'; } 
        ?>

        <a class="btn btn-primary"href="nuevoempleado.php?vista=addEmpleado" style="color:#FFF;">Agregar Empleado</a>

        <table class="table table-sm table-bordered" style="width:400px;">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>

            <?php
            #CONSULTAR LOS EMPLEADOS
            $query = "SELECT * FROM empleado";
            if($resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){

                #RECORRES EL RESULTADO CON FOREACH Y LE PONES NOMBRE A LAS VARIABLES
                foreach($resultado as $rows){
                    $id =$rows['id'];
                    $nombre =$rows['nombre'];
                    $edad =$rows['edad'];
                
                    echo "
                        <tr>
                            <td>$id</td>
                            <td>$nombre</td>
                            <td>$edad</td>
                            <td><a href='acciones.php?action=eliminarEmpleado&id=$id'>Borrar</a> <a href='nuevoempleado.php?vista=updateEmpleado&id=$id'>Modificar</a></td>
                        </tr>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ACCIONES.PHP**

```
<?php
#TU CONEXION
include_once('basededatos.php');

#VARIABLE PARA IDENTIFICAR QUE HARÁ
$accion=$_GET['action'];

#AGREGAR A UN EMPLEADO
if($accion == "add_empleado"){

    #RECIBES LA VARIABLE POR POST
    $nom_empleado=$_POST['nombre'];
    $edad_empleado=$_POST['edad'];

    #HACES LA CONSULTA DE TIPO INSERT
    $query = "INSERT INTO empleado (nombre,edad) VALUES ('$nom_empleado','$edad_empleado')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    #EVALUAS QUE HACER SI SE EJECUTÓ LA CONSULTA O NO
    if($result){
        $alerta= "Se agregó el empleado";
        header("Location: listaempleados.php?alerta=$alerta");
    } else{
        $alerta= "Error al agregar, intente de nuevo";
        header("Location: nuevoempleado.php?vista=addEmpleado&alerta=$alerta");
    }
}

#ELIMINAR A UN EMPLEADO
if($accion == "eliminarEmpleado"){

    #RECIBES LA VARIABLE POR GET
    $id_empleado = $_GET['id'];

    #HACES LA CONSULTA DE TIPO DELETE
    $query = "DELETE FROM empleado WHERE id = $id_empleado";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    #EVALUAS QUE HACER SI SE EJECUTÓ LA CONSULTA O NO
    if($result){
        $alerta= "Se eliminó el empleado";
        header("Location: listaempleados.php?alerta=$alerta");
    }else{
        $alerta= "Ocurrio un error al eliminar";
        header("Location: listaempleados.php?alerta=$alerta");
    }

}

#ACTUALIZAR A UN EMPLEADO
if($accion == "modificarEmpleado"){

    #RECIBES LAS VARIABLES POR POST
    $id_empleado = $_POST['id'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $edad = $_POST['edad'];

    #HACES LA CONSULTA DE TIPO UPDATE
    $query = "UPDATE empleado SET nombre = '$nombre', edad = '$edad' WHERE id = $id_empleado";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    #EVALUAS QUE HACER SI SE EJECUTÓ LA CONSULTA O NO
    if($result){
        $alerta= "Se Actualizó al empleado #$id_empleado";
        header("Location: listaempleados.php?alerta=$alerta");
    }else{
        $alerta= "Ocurrio un error al actualizar";
        header("Location: listaempleados.php?alerta=$alerta");
    }
}
?>
```

Y así es como se ve la **Base de datos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenta comprender el código que te puse, cualquier duda puedes escribir un comentario o en FB

Answer (score -1):

Actualice el código, realice una consulta en SQL, para que ande al cargar la base de datos, papá me explico algo sabe sobre el tema y me ayuda pero, lo que cargue ayer tenía problemas en la sintaxis, me fije en internet y modifique. Solo me falta que la consulta sql se conecte digamos para que al actualizar un empleado lo modifique.

acciones.php

```
      if($accion == "modificarempleado"){
    
        $id_empleado = $_GET['id'];
        $edad_empleado=$_POST['edad'];
        $nom_empleado=$_POST['nombre'];
        
    
        $query = "UPDATE `empleado` SET 
        `id`='$id_empleado,`nombre`=$nom_empleado,`edad`= $edad_empleado 
        WHERE  id = 1";
        echo $query;
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if($result){
            $alerta= "Se modifico el empleado";
            header("Location: modificarempleado.php?alerta=$alerta");
        }else{
            $alerta= "Ocurrio un error al modificar el 
         empleado,vuelve a 
          intentarlo";
            echo $alerta;
            header("Location: modificarempleado.php");
    
    
    }
}
```

Modificarempleado.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Modificar empleado</title>
      <link href="...5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php 
            #MUESTRA UNA ALERTA
            if(isset($_GET['alerta'])){ echo '<script> 
        Swal.fire("'.$_GET['alerta'].'") </script>'; } 
        ?>

        <h1>Modificar empleado</h1>
        <form action="acciones.php?action=modificarempleado" 
            method="post" name="modificarempleado" style="width: 
         400px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" 
            placeholder="Nombre">
            </br>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="edad" 
            placeholder="Edad">
            </br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="Modificar 
            empleado">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ustedes me dirán.
saludos.

Comment: No sé de donde seas, pero puedo ayudarte con tu código mañana, en realidad en vez de hacer un **SELECT**, debes hacer un **UPDATE**

Comment: Hola, Ya te actualicé el código en la respuesta que te hice hace unos días. revísalo. Espero que te sirva. Básicamente hiciste un **CRUD** (actualizar, insertar, borrar, ver registros). Si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides marcarla como correcta, saludos

Comment: Hola! funciona, lo único que no anda es cuando quiero agregar un empleado. Lo de modificar anda.

Comment: Dice que no reconoce la variable vista en nuevoempleado.php

Comment: Es correcto, cuando intentas abrir el archivo **nuevoempleado.php**, Acabo de actualizarte ese archivo. Ya no te saldrá ese error

Comment: Esto no es una respuesta. Por favor, edita tu pregunta con la nueva informacion.